# Does there exist a joint CDF of a random number of random variables?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given a positive discrete random variable $N$ and a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$, we can calculate the CDF of $Y=\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$ indirectly by using moment-generating functions: $M_Y(s)=M_N(\ln M_{X_1}(s))$. I believe that the CDF of Y always exists as long as $M_{X_1}$ is well defined, i.e. finite in $[-c,c]$ for some positive real number $c$ (but please correct me if I am wrong).

Does there exist a joint CDF of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$? Given $N=n$, it seems we can have a conditional CDF $F_{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N|N=n}$. But if we define a random vector $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$, then $\mathbf E[X]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf E[X|N=n]p_N(n)$ would be a sum of vectors in vector spaces of different dimensions. What can we "expect" if we draw a random vector from a vector space of a random dimension?

This led me to take a step back. What does the probability space underlying the random variables $N,X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$, which are common to both problems, look like?

Comment: The CDF of $Y$ always exists because it is a random variable. (Finiteness of a MGF is not needed.)

Comment: @nejimban Why is $Y$ a random variable? We know that any real-valued function of a fixed number of random variables is a random variable. However, that does not immediately lead to the conclusion that any real-valued function of a random number of random variables is a random variable.

Comment: In my current understanding, the outcome set $\Omega$ consists of tuples of different lengths, and for $i=1,2,\ldots$, $X_i$ is a projection function mapping each tuple to the $i$-th coordinate. However, only $X_1$ is well defined. For example, $X_2$ is not defined for monads as they have no second coordinate. So, $X_2$ is not even a function (hence not a random variable) unless it is restricted to a subset of the outcome set without the monads.

Comment: You can write $Y\colon\Omega\to\Bbb R$ as $$Y(\omega):=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{\{i\le N(\omega)\}}X_i(\omega).$$ It is clearly a random variable (as pointwise limit of random variables).

Comment: Regarding the probability space, there are many possible $\Omega$ which embeds $N$ and the sequence $(X_i)_{i\ge1}$ (and thus also $Y$). A concrete example of $\Omega$ can be constructed explicitly from the canonical space $((0,1),\Bbb B(0,1),\text{Leb})$.